# How do I insert new fields into $self in Perl, from a File::Find callback

Tags: perl, oop

In a Perl object, I'm trying to add a new field into `$self` from within a File::Find `wanted()` sub.

```
use File::Find;

sub _searchForXMLDocument {
    my ($self) = @_; 
    if($_ =~ /[.]+\.xml/) {
        $self->{_xmlDocumentPath} = $_;
    }
}


sub runIt{
    my ($self) = @_;
    find (\&_searchForXMLDocument, $self->{_path});
    print $self->{_xmlDocumentPath};
}
```

`_searchForXMLDocument()` searches for an XML Document within `$self->{_path}` and is supposed to append that XML path to `$self->{_xmlDocumentPath}` but when I try to print it, it remains uninitialized. How do I add the field in `$self`?

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at /home/scott/workspace/CCGet/XMLProcessor.pm line 51.
```

Comment: Can you add detail about `find`? Is it a method in this class, or from a library?

Comment: It's from File::Find.  I think I've got it sorted for him now, aside from possibly explaining the closure more if he needs it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling _searchForXMLDocument() in an OO manner, so your $self object isn't being passed to it.  This should do the trick now. Use a closure for your method and you have access to $self;

```
sub runIt{
    my ($self) = @_;

    my $closure = sub {
        if($_ !~ m/[.]+\.xml/) {
            $self->{_xmlDocumentPath} = $_;
        }
    };

    find(\&$closure, $self->{_path});
    print $self->{_xmlDocumentPath};
}
```

Comment: I'm confused to how $self->_searchForXMLDocument() passes in $self. What is happening exactly when you reference that subroutine with $self?

Comment: When you call a method using OO syntax, Perl automagically passes a copy of the object as the first parameter.  When you call using procedural syntax, the method/function doesn't get a copy of the object.  Unfortunately, per my edit, this still doesn't seem to quite be working, but the reasoning is correct.

Comment: Updated the code for you to something that works.  This uses a closure within your runIt() method so that it has access to $self since the code ref that find() wants cannot take any arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `find()` needs to carry two pieces of information: the test condition, and the object you're working with. The way to do this is with a closure. The `sub { ... }` creates a code ref, like you get from `\&_searchForXMLDocument`, but the closure has access to lexical variables in the enclosing scope, so the current object (`$self`) is associated with the closure.

```
sub _searchForXMLDocument {
    my ($self) = @_;
    if($_ =~ /[.]+\.xml/) {
        $self->{_xmlDocumentPath} = $_;
    }
}


sub runIt{
    my ($self) = @_;
    find (sub { $self->_searchForXMLDocument (@_) }, $self->{_path});
    print $self->{_xmlDocumentPath};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
package XMLDocThing;
use strict;
use warnings;
use English    qw<$EVAL_ERROR>;
use File::Find qw<find>;
...

use constant MY_BREAK = do { \my $v = 133; };

sub find_XML_document { 
    my $self = shift;
    eval { 
        find( sub {
                 return unless m/[.]+\.xml/;
                 $self->{_xmlDocumentPath} = $_;
                 die MY_BREAK;
              }
            , $self->{_path} 
            );
    };
    if ( my $error = $EVAL_ERROR ) { 
        die Carp::longmess( $EVAL_ERROR ) unless $error == MY_BREAK;
    }
}

...
# meanwhile, in some other package...

$xmldocthing->find_XML_document;
```

You pass a closure to find and it can access `$self` from the containing scope. `File::Find::find` has no capacity to pass in baggage like objects.